# How to install ruby 2.3.4 on windows without the RubyInstaller 2.3.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, installation

I have to stick with the version 2.3.4 mandatorily and I am not able to find any windows installer to install ruby 2.3.4. The only resource I found is a tar/zip file that is available at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/30/ruby-2-3-4-released/

I have no idea how to install this,I struggled doing the same using PIK but that couldn't help either,can someone please provide some suggestions how to install 2.3.4 version of ruby.

Comment: Wow, 0 effort from you. If you would have looked into the naviagtion of your Link you would see "Download" and voila there is a section `Ways of Installing Ruby` which leads for windows to https://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: @mrkernelpanic if I would have found an installer for the version 2.3.4 in the archives of rubyinstaller.org, why on earth would I go through the trouble of posting a question here.

Comment: If you are absolutely stuck with that exact version without deviation, you are going to have to probably build from source. On Windows, this is not fun. You need to install a ming, msys, etc. get it all setup properly (all not fun, even for people who know what they are doing). Are you certain you need 2.3.4, that is a strangely specific requirement.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 It is indeed a strange requirement. I am trying to set up sharetribe locally; in their documentation, Sharetribe specifically asks you to set up Ruby 2.3.4. I tried setting it up with other versions of Ruby but they won't work :(

Comment: @stark45 if you have access to the Sharetribe `Gemfile` just change `ruby '2.3.4'` into `ruby '2.3.3'` or whatever version (2.4 shouldn't cause a lots incompatibilities issue with an Rails app)

Comment: @stark45 were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Janjua I found a work around with the latest version

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [Rails installer for Windows, with Ruby 2.3.3](http://railsinstaller.org/en). It includes Ruby, Devkit and Git.

Answer (score -1):

> We have several tools on each major platform to install Ruby:
>
> ...
>   On Windows machines, you can use RubyInstaller.

https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

But the last ruby installer hotfix version is 2.3.3 for 2.3 version and without Devkit, which is almost mandatory on Windows.

https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/

So i recommend you to upgrade your Ruby version or switch environment since Windows is painfull and not for beginner (lots of issues with gems using C language).

Upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4 (for example)
https://wyeworks.com/blog/2016/6/22/behavior-changes-in-ruby-2.4

Comment: Definitely don't go without DevKit. You will be quite screwed trying to install a vast number of extremely common and useful gems. It is bigger install, but as stated here, practically necessary on a non-*nix machine.